# NSMutableArray addObject crashes in the device but runs in the simulator fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have a set of images in my project like this,

[image]

I'm trying to get them all in to a mutable array, Like so,

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:36] retain];
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"quicktour_%d.JPG",i+1]] autorelease];
    [imageArray addObject:image];
}
```

This runs in the simulator just fine but crashes when I run in a device after adding like 5 images.

Its a non-ARC project. I went through all the similar questions here on SO and tried the solutions posted there but my problem is still there.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the output that shows in the console when crashing.

> ***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM
>   insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2f784f4b 0x39bc56af 0x2f6bec81 0x138987 0x31f2c713 0x31f2c6b3 0x31f2c691 0x31f1811f 0x31f2c107 0x31f2bdd9
>   0x31f26e65 0x31efc79d 0x31efafa3 0x2f750183 0x2f74f653 0x2f74de47
>   0x2f6b8c27 0x2f6b8a0b 0x343df283 0x31f5c049 0x1f9ab 0x3a0cdab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException**

Comment: Can you please provide the crash log?

Comment: paste your crash log . i think its because of memory overflow on device. your are adding so much memory (check image size) at run time.

Comment: You are over releasing the images (ImageNamed: returns an autoreleased image already, there is no need to autorelease) and over-retaining your image array (init methods return an object with a retain count of +1, and are not autoreleased). Reread the rules of manual memory management in the Apple docs. 

The other posters are probably right about the nil issue, but its not going to help you at all because at the end of the day you're going to have an array with garbage values in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object passed to `addObject:` *must not be nil* according to the docs. Chances are your fifth image is named such that the capitalization doesn't match what you're asking for, and the `imageNamed:` call therefore returns nil. The iOS file system is case sensitive, but the OS X file system (usually) isn't; problems that appear only on the device are often related to this fact.

You can fix the file name to prevent the crash, but you should really have your code check for nil before adding the object to the array.

Comment: This was it! Man, I was pulling my hair out. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure you are adding to the array?
2. Add an NSLog statement after your assignment, it will slow down a bit on the device, but, you are crashing either because you are not adding anything or you are adding something that does not exist
3. Furthermore, I would again use NSLog to show the path of the image, you would be surprised probably to find out that the image is not in the right path
4. And now, for complete reversal of logic.  Try the same code in a separate project, with ARC enabled.  Do you have the same problem? If not, it is a memory issue, i.e. the autorelease statement, because "autorelease" works only at the end of the autorelease pool, so you are probable piling up image as you go along, which is not a good thing.

I would change your code to :

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:36] retain];
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"quicktour_%d.JPG",i+1]];
    [imageArray addObject:image];
    [image release];
    image = nil;
}
```

Comment: Your code has the same problem as the OP's, i.e. it'll crash if `-imageNamed:` returns nil, which it will do if the requested image isn't available. Check for nil before adding to the array.